# How to make an android/iOS system event listener in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

In my app, I want to make an `event listener`. For example, if a saved number calls or messages, it should perform an action. Is this possible to do, even if application is not running in the background?

Comment: What did you try so far? any code snippets? I think you have pretty rich community for question like yours: https://forum.ionicframework.com/?utm_source=framework&utm_medium=navbar&utm_campaign=forum%20CTA

Comment: @MaximShoustin you are right but what I exactly learned is from stackoverflow. This code will help us to send goods's price change or sale plan's change to salesperson by SMS. when they are not connected to internet or any connection issue was occurred.